# How to convert an array and an object to enable one-to-one correspondence?

Tags: javascript

For example I have an Array `var array = [1001, 1002, 1003]`

And I want to convert this array to an Object like

```
var obj = {
  a: 1001,
  b: 1002,
  c: 1003
}
```

I think the easiest way is to do like

```
obj.a = array[0]
obj.b = array[1]
obj.c = array[2]
```

However is there have any good ways to do this job and without using `for` cycle?(because i think if `array.length < 5`, use `obj.x = array[y]` will be more efficient?)

And I aslo want to know how to change the `obj` to a new empty array like?

```
// first get this obj
var obj = {
  a: 1001,
  b: 1002,
  c: 1003
}
// and then create this new array
var newArray = []
for(let i in obj) {
  newArray.push(obj[i])
}
console.log(newArray) // [1001, 1002, 1003]
```

Does `es6` have a good ways to solve this convert from each other ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `for`? It seems like the most natural way to do this.

Comment: change the obj to a new empty array also the same as the array => any example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let array = [1001, 1002, 1003]

let obj = array.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
    acc[`id${idx + 1}`] = curr;
    return acc;
    

}, {})

console.log(obj)

// if you want the original array back you can use Object.values
console.log(Object.values(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.Entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (it is not necessary but it is a cool way and more readable when you want to convert array to object) with [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```js
const array = [1001, 1002, 1003];
const result = Object.fromEntries(array.reduce((m,n,i)=>[...m, [`id${++i}`, n]], []));

console.log({array, result});
```